# Building android project in a docker container builds only intermediates folder

Tags: android, docker, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm building a simple project inside docker (image with android-sdk and gradle 6.5)
The code, I'm pulling has no gradle wrapper. Thus I use this code:

```
cd "Sample Code"
gradle wrapper --gradle-version 6.7.1 --distribution-type all
gradle :sample:assemble
```

The output I get in build folder is only intermediates dir, no generated, no outputs apk, etc. The build.gradle of project level and on app level are present. No failures observed in logs.
What am I missing? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My fault. It appears that `gradle` build creates two folders named build: one on the **project-level** and another one at the **module level**. The build folder on the project-level (which I was thinking of as a complete build folder) contains only intermediates. The directory you need in order to get an `.apk` is the build folder under the module directory (in my case I needed to `cd` to sample folder), this folder contains all the build output.